# An error of the function which converts data from SVGimage format to xmlDocPtr formant

Tags: c

I am working on an small web-developing project.
Frontend : Javascript Jquery HTML
Backend : Node.js + C

This project includes functions of creation, validate, adding a shape, setting attributes(etc..) SVG files and shows the files in Firefox web-browsers (This project should run on Linux OS).

All functions of handling the SVGfiles are developed in C and calls the functions in Node.js with **ffi-napi** module.
On developing I have an error in the function which converts data from SVGimage format to xmlDocPtr format.

> The C code error position is attached below:
>
> "error : string is not in UTF-8"

```
if (image->rectangles) {
    iter = createIterator(image->rectangles);
    Rectangle* rect = NULL;
    while ((rect = nextElement(&iter)) != NULL)
    {
        node = xmlNewChild(root_node, NULL, BAD_CAST "rect", NULL);
        sprintf(buf, "%.2f%s", rect->x, rect->units);
        xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "x", BAD_CAST buf);
        sprintf(buf, "%.2f%s", rect->y, rect->units);
        xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "y", BAD_CAST buf);
        sprintf(buf, "%.2f%s", rect->width, rect->units);
        xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "width", BAD_CAST buf);
        sprintf(buf, "%.2f%s", rect->height, rect->units);
        xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "height", BAD_CAST buf);
        
        if (!addAttributesToNode(node, rect->otherAttributes)) {
            fail = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
bool addAttributesToNode(xmlNodePtr node, List* attributes)
{
    if (node == NULL || attributes == NULL)
        return false;

    ListIterator iter = createIterator(attributes);
    Attribute* attr = NULL;
    while ((attr = nextElement(&iter)) != NULL)
    {
        if (attr->name == NULL)
            return false;
        xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST attr->name, BAD_CAST attr->value);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have no errors when I run this project on chrome with Win 10 OS:
But when deploying this project on Linux OS(Centos 7) I have this error.
I am looking for a help of solving out this problem...